# Ascending python text

Tags: python

I have simple problem, i created game and in the end I append score to textfile. Now i have something like this in this file:

```
John: 11
Mike: 5
John: 78
John: 3
Steve: 30
```

i want give user possibility to read top 3 scores. Now i created this:

```
with open(r'C:/path/to/scores.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                data = line.split()
                print '{0[0]:<15}{0[1]:<15}'.format(data)
```

I have this:

```
John:       11             
Mike:       5             
John:       78            
John:       3             
Steve:      30
```

It looks better but how can i show only three best results with place and highest first etc?

Something like that:

```
 1.   John:       78 
 2.   Steve:      30 
 3.   John:       11
```

Comment: That procedure is called "sorting".

Comment: Put that data in a dict with the score being the key. Then sort the dict by key value and print only the first 3 ones

Comment: @Alexander: A dict would be inappropriate, since the "keys" (names) aren't unique. And it wouldn't gain you anything over sorting a `list` of `tuple` pairs anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your code a little bit to store the scores in a list, then sort them using the `sorted` function. Then you can just take the first three scores of your sorted list.

```
with open(r'doc.txt', 'r') as f:
            scores = []
            for line in f:
                data = line.split()
                scores.append(data)

            top3 = sorted(scores, key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)[:3]

            for score in top3:
                print '{0[0]:<15}{0[1]:<15}'.format(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

As in [my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33000095/how-do-i-sort-data-highest-to-lowest-in-python-from-a-text-file/33000232#33000232), the answer could be just used `sorted`; slicing the result to get only three top scores is trivial.

That said, you could also switch to using [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) over `sorted` in this case; it takes a `key` function, just like `sorted`, and unlike `sorted`, it will only use memory to store the top X items (and has better theoretical performance when the set to extract from is large and the number of items to keep is small). Aside from not needing `reverse=True` (because choosing `nlargest` already does that), `heapq.nlargest` is a drop in replacement for `sorted` from that case.

Comment: When I say "similar", I really mean it. That other question is sorting the same sort of name/integer value pairs in lines read from a file, and you should really take a look at it for a starting point; the only difference is in trivial aspects of the formatting and whether you use `sorted` or `heapq.nlargest`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you might want to do with the data I think `pandas` is a great option here.  You can load it into `pandas` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = []
with open(r'C:/path/to/scores.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                data = line.split()
                df.append({'Name': data[0], 'Score': data[1]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Then you can sort by score and show the top three

```
df.sort('Score', ascending=False)[:3]
```

I recommend reading all of the pandas [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) to see everything it can do

**EDIT:** For easier reading you can do something like

```
df = pd.read_table('C:/path/to/scores.txt')
```

But this would require you to put column headings in that file first

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(r'C:/path/to/scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    scores = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split()
        scores.append((line[0], int(line[1]))

    sorted_scores = sorted(scores, key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)
    top_three = sorted_scores[:3]
```

This will read every line, strip extra whitespace, and split the line, then append it to the `scores` list. Once all scores have been added, the list gets sorted using the `key` of the 2nd item in the `(name, score)` tuple, in reverse, so that the scores run from high-to-low. Then the `top_three` slices the first 3 items from the sorted scores.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, and depending on your coding style, you could certainly consolidate some of these lines.  For the sake of the example, I simply have the contents of your score file in a string:

```
score_file_contents = """John: 11
Mike: 5
John: 78
John: 3
Steve: 30"""

scores = []
for line in score_file_contents.splitlines():  # Simulate reading your file
    name, score = line.split(':')  # Extract name and score
    score = int(score)  # Want score as an integer
    scores.append((score, name))  # Make my list

scores.sort(reverse=True)  # List of tuples sorts on first tuple element
for ranking in range(len(scores)):  # Iterate using an index
    if ranking < 3:  # How many you want to show
        score = scores[ranking][0]  # Extract score
        name = scores[ranking][1]  # Extract name
        print("{}.  {:<10} {:<3}".format(ranking + 1, name + ":", score))
```

Result:

```
1.  John:      78 
2.  Steve:     30 
3.  John:      11
```